# Excel 2010 copy cell to new cell if text found

Tags: excel-2010

I have this formula that needs modification. If I find the string "JOB-20" in column A:F in row 1, I want to copy the date to the right of where the string was found to a new cell. Currently it just enters whatever is in B1. How can I modify this? Or is this not the best formula for doing this?  Thanks for your help!

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:F1,"JOB-20"),B1,"")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 =INDEX(A1:F1;1;MATCH("*JOB-20*";A1:F1;0)+1)
```

The MATCH function returns the column index were you find (the first time in the row) the pattern specified.

The INDEX function returns the content of the cell specified on the 2nd and third param, over the matrix defined at first param.

Hope i was clear, feel free to ask

EDIT, handlig error values

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:F1;1;MATCH("*JOB-20*";A1:F1;0)+1);"")
```

Comment: this works great. How can I keep the cell with this formula blank if there is nothing found?  Right now I just get #N/A

Comment: use IFERROR (Result of the function;0)

Comment: I'm blind this morning.... Thanks for your help! This works GREAT! Just what I needed.